# UpdatePanel does not appear on default load, but it does when specific page is given

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I got my hands on a this web application few days back and I am already stuck with  a problem.

When I load the page with, say, HL1 = `http://localhost:8001/`, UpdatePanel does not appear at all.

Though when I load the page with HL2 = `http://localhost:8001/Default.aspx`, it displays in its full glory.

[EDIT: Added HL1, HL2 tags]

FYI, UpdatePanel is part of a Master page.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Abhinav

[EDIT: Code for update panel]

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upan" runat="server" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <fieldset style="width:320px; padding:2px;margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:5px;" onmouseover="showHelp('quickAccess')" onmouseout="g_Popup.hide()">
            <legend>Quick Access</legend>
            <span style="vertical-align: middle">Dummy #
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchDummy" clientidmode="Static" runat="server" MaxLength="9" Width="70px" Height="15px" style="margin-top: 5px"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID = "btnSearchDummy" clientidmode="Static" runat="server" OnClick="btnSearchDummy_Click" style="display:none"/>
            <button onclick="return quickAccess()"  lang="javascript" type="submit" class="button_enabled" style="margin-left: 5px;">
            <img alt="" src="images/lightning.gif"></img><span>Find Dummy</span></button></span>
        </fieldset>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Is Default.aspx, the default page declared in your project properties?

Comment: And does the rest of the (master) page appear? You will need to provide much more details.

Comment: Just to add, I am a Windows App developer, this Web App is for the time being only. @Praveen no it wasn't the default page, I have just made it as a default page, error is still there though.

Comment: @Henk-Holterman Yes the rest of the page appears perfectly. To be honest I have very little idea what extra info I can provide. Anything specific you want me to look into?

Comment: Put a Label(Text="Master") on the master page and another one (Text="Default") on the Default content page. Report which one you see and when.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I added 3 labels, 1st before the UpdatePanel, 2nd after UpdatePanel both on the Master Page and 3rd one on the Default.aspx page. All three labels were rendered but UpdatePanel still did not show up using HL1 but it does using HL2 just as before.

Comment: How do you determine "does not show up", what are the controls on the Updatepanel?  Post the relevant parts of the ASPX.

Comment: Added code for update panel. I look at the rendered HTML source to verify if the update panel is being rendered at all. I can see it there when opening HL2 but not HL1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help guys. Issue is resolved now and, as expected, it had nothing to do with ASP.NET. In master page code behind file that search box was being made invisible.

:)